# React Variable Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, provider

I want to make a React Component where i can Input a Context from createContext and add the Provider to it. The Context Variable should be changeable like a State Variable (like useState).
It should look like this, but the code below is not working obviously:

```
<div>
   <{CONTEXT VARIABLE HERE}.Provider value={value}>
       all the stuff inside...
   </{CONTEXT VARIABLE HERE}.Provider>
</div>
```

I tried to just place a variable for this but this didnt work. I also tried to make a Component where it returns the Provider if a specific value is 0 or 1 or 2...
I figured out that if a State is over the Provider the Provider laggs or in an input field it only let you place on character and then get out of focus.